# Android - Image View not displaying photo

Tags: java, android, image

Quick question, this is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/our_photo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/our_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_photo"
    android:onClick="TakePhoto" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/load_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/show_photo"
    android:onClick="ShowPhoto" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/our_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/file_directory" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

And this is my code where I try to display an image loaded from gallery (image has just been created, so it does exist, it loads it - in debug mode I can see that myBitmap object is not a null) but it does not display anything. I tried to create a black bitmap just to see if it's a layout defect but it shows it fine, it just does not currently work with a file.

```
public void ShowPhoto(View v) {
    File imgFile = new  File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    if(imgFile.exists()){
         //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        try {
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream    (imgFile),null,o);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        //The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE_X=240;
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE_Y=400;

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale=1;
        while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE_X && o.outHeight/ scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE_Y)
            scale*=2;

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        Bitmap myBitmap=null;
        try {
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(imgFile), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point screenSize = new Point();
        display.getSize(screenSize);
        //imageView.setMinimumHeight(screenSize.y/2);
        //imageView.setMinimumWidth(screenSize.x/2);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, screenSize.x/2, screenSize.y/2, false));
    }
```

In debug mode there are no exceptions etc. it all just goes well and there are no results.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you referenced your image view?

Comment: Mitesh, that's it! I was using the imageView variable as a global variable and referenced it only during the on create method which correctly displayed the black bitmap. I have referrenced it now and it worked indeed! Thank you so much for such a simple and correct answer! Cheers mate.

Comment: @user1619684 then you should accept his answer if that help you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have forgot to reference your `ImageView`.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.our_photo);
```